# Start other vendor soft from IIS AppPool\{someuser} or built-in NETWORK SERVICE with disk write/read permission

Tags: c#, iis, permissions, windows-server-2012-r2

I have IIS with site which recieve tasks through hangfire system. It should execute some code and then via Process.Start() execute other vendor software (ANSYS). ANSYS should start and do some file operations. This scheme works fine at local machine under my usual windows account. But under IIS AppPool{PoolName} or under NT AUTORITY\NETWORK SERVICE hangfire task can't start ANSYS. 
I gave full permissions for ANSYS's folder and for folder to make disk w/r operations. I tried to place these accounts to Administrator group but has had the same result.
How can I gave permissions to execute and make disk operations for IIS AppPool{PoolName} or NT AUTORITY\NETWORK SERVICE?

Comment: `hangfire task can't start ANSYS` What made you come to that conclusion? What exception was thrown? What was logged? What is shown in Event Viewer?

Comment: @mjwills we use own schedule system based on https://www.hangfire.io/
 which execute our C# code compiled in basic dlls. So my dll start ANSYS in "batch-mode" via usual C# Process.Start()

Comment: @sad1002 you didn't answer the question. Also, you can change the app pool to run as a user, and specify 'load user profile' setting to ensure the software has access to full resources. that said, however, i am not sure that you will get an interactive session.